# webrick became very slow after I use active_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

Notice how time-consuming to finish a request

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-10-19 20:45:38 +0800
Processing by MainController#index as HTML
Book Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" 
Rendered application/_product.html.erb (66.8ms)
Rendered main/index.html.erb within layouts/application (158.7ms)
Rendered application/_header.html.erb (45.6ms)
Rendered application/_search_cart.html.erb (1.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 350ms (Views: 347.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

Any idea?

What else choice do I have to replace webrick as a default server!

Comment: Try out [active_reload](https://github.com/paneq/active_reload). It may or may not help. Just experiment.

Comment: I think my answer to this similar question also answers yours:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826885/active-admin-slowing-down-rails-applicaton/7833222#7833222

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use rails-dev-boost gem (https://github.com/thedarkone/rails-dev-boost) , add the following to your gemfile and do a bundle install

```
gem 'rails-dev-boost', :git => 'https://github.com/thedarkone/rails-dev-boost.git', :require => 'rails_development_boost'
```

but beware, restarts of your server remain necessary when changing code in lib/ folders, in initializers and so on.

you could also try getting mongrel to work as a development server. Depending on your ruby/rails combination the following would change. More clues and information on : http://jan.varwig.org/archive/rails-3-and-mongrel, this should work for rails 3.1 and ruby 1.9.2 combo

```
group :development, :test do
  # ...
  # http://jan.varwig.org/archive/rails-3-and-mongrel
  gem 'mongrel', '>= 1.2.0.pre2'
end
```